# How to bundle a wrapper jar using maven which includes my code's class files and third party jars as is?

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I am new to Maven and facing below mentioned issue -

I want to bundle all the modules which are being used by a parent/root module ( which contains main class ) into a single jar.

For Example :

Root application - module which contains main class and need all below jars as dependencies

- a.jar ( child module jars built individually using maven ) - refers spring dependency
- b.jar ( child module jars built individually using maven ) - refers hibernate dependency
- c.jar ( child module jars built individually using maven ) - refers log4j dependency

I'd like to generate jar for Root application which can include .class/jars of a,b,c modules but should not include .class files for third party frameworks like spring, hibernate, etc.

Constraint -

- I can not bundle whole module and dependencies in a Zip but in jar only
- all jars/files under this jar should be on classpath if I put root jar on classpath

Let me inform that I've already tried maven's 
 `<descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>` using "maven-assembly-plugin" but this gives me exploded ( .class files ) folder structure inside the jar, even for third party framework classes. Hence I can see folder structure like

root-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar\org\springframework\aop\*.class

I am looking something like :

root-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -

- main.class
- lib/a.jar ( jar Or exploded .class folder structure )
- lib/b.jar ( jar Or exploded .class folder structure )
- lib/c.jar ( jar Or exploded .class folder structure )
- lib/spring.jar ( Jar only )
- lib/hibernate.jar ( Jar only )
- lib/log4j.jar ( Jar only )

Ultimately all jars should be accessible by main.class whether they lie within  /lib or in any other location within the root jar

Comment: You're probably looking for the [shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) to create an "uber-jar".